# How to run mocha test parser on deployments with bamboo

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, bamboo

I'm running mocha tests as part of a deployment process and need to use mocha test parser for bamboo to know what failed (using reporter mocha-bamboo-reporter). 
Mocha test parser task is only able to run during the build process (it can't be added as part of a deployment process). Is there a way to run it from a command, node.js or npm task?

Currently when tests fail bamboo is still saying that the deployment was ok.
Test run configuration: 
[config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYjSf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you would only want to run your tests as part of the build process and not the deployment process.  This is why you do not see these options as part of the deployment. Generally, Bamboo deployment failures are the result of files not copying, connection errors, or errors in scripts.

Because you are running tests in the deployment, the test runner will return "0" indicating that the task to execute the tests ran fine.  Bamboo allows you to do this so that you can run tests as a deployment and still deploy.

Instead of failing the deploy, add two tasks to the build to run the tests and parse the results.  If the tests pass you can have the deploy trigger on the success of the build.  This gives you the following advantages that you are currently missing:

1. Deployments only will start if tests pass.
2. Bamboo has a nice summary page for tests and will provide useful metrics such as how many times a specific test has failed.
3. It separates the deployment from the integration (i.e. build/test).

However, if you are dead set on running tests and parsing in a deployment, you could have a node.js, command, or script task that parses the results and then returns -1 (or a non-zero number) if tests failed.